# What is wrong with this PHP function

Tags: php, regex, function, syntax-error

I am new to `PHP` and regular expression. I was going thorugh some online examples and came with this example:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}, 'hello-world');
// outputs helloWorld
?>
```

in `php.net` but to my surprise it does not work and keep getting error:

```
PHP Parse error:  parse error, unexpected T_FUNCTION
```

Why get error ?

Comment: what version of PHP are you running this on ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using PHP's [Anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php): functions that have **no name**.

When I run your program I get no error. May be you are trying it on a `PHP < 5.3`.

**Anonymous functions are available since PHP 5.3.0.**

If `PHP` version is creating the problem you can re-write the program to **not use** Anonymous functions as:

```
<?php

// a callback function called in place of anonymous function.
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~','fun', 'hello-world');

// the call back function.
function fun($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}

?>
```

Comment: @unicornaddict: the second argument to `preg_replace_callback` should be a string in this particular case.

Comment: @salathe: Thanks for pointing. Interestingly even not quoting worked here with a Notice :). Looks like OP also did not see the Notice :)

Answer (score 2):

This example is for PHP 5.3. You probably use something older (e.g., PHP 5.2).

Try this instead:

```
<?php
function callback($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', 'callback', 'hello-world');
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a version prior to PHP 5.3.0?  [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) are not supported in versions prior to that one.

You can check your version with a [phpinfo](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) page.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on pre-5.3 versions:

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
        '/-([a-z])/',     
        create_function( '$arg', 'return strtoupper($arg[1]);' ),
        'hello-world'
     );
```

Regards

rbo